# Diffing two directories recursively based on checksums?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, diff, recursive, checksum

I'm trying to find what files don't exist by a checksum of their content. I have two directories `/foo` and `/bar`, both of these directories represent arbitrary states on the system, I want to find all *files* in root `/bar` that do not exist in root `/foo` (recursively). A dictionary of `/bar/**` with

```
CheckSum -> filepath
```

less the dictionary of `/foo/**` with

```
CheckSum -> filepath
```

I can write this using md5sum or something, but there must already be a utility that does this.

Just to be clear, if two files are identical *except* by location (name and path) I want them to be identified as the same.

### Test case

Let's create a tree with some test data,

```
/tmp/foo
└── myFile (duplicate of /tmp/bar/quz/asdf/otherFileName)
/tmp/bar
├── qaz
│   └── findMe
└── quz
    └── asdf
        └── otherFileName (duplicate of /tmp/foo/myFile)
```

Script for creation,

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo /tmp/bar/quz/asdf /tmp/bar/qaz

# One file that exists in both locations
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/foo/myFile bs=1k count=10
cp /tmp/foo/myFile /tmp/bar/quz/asdf/otherFileName

# One file (findMe) that exists in only /mpt/bar/
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/bar/qaz/findMe bs=1k count=10
```

So the program comparing `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/bar` should find `/tmp/bar/qaz/findMe`

Comment: Is the checksum that important? finding all files in `bar` that are not in `foo` or that are `diff`erent in `foo` (that's what you want, right?) is a matter of roughly one `find` command.

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 2):

I'd generate an md5sum listing (a column for sum, and a column for filename) for both trees and pipe the result into a script (say awk or perl) which can use the sum as a hash for the filenames, and make the script report filenames which have the same hash value.

That's more than a one-liner, and is something frequently asked, frequently solved (a web search for duplicate files by content comes up with more than a million hits).

You might find this helpful:

- [Finding duplicate files?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202639/finding-duplicate-files)

Comment: I've written it in multiple different languages myself, I'm just wondering if there is any reasonably ubiquitous unix command that can do this.