# Difference between diff and sum utilities

Tags: diff, checksum, file-comparison, integrity

We use diff for finding difference between two files. We use checksum utilities for finding hashes and compare them later. In this regards, I have some questions :

1. Can we diff any type of file ? For example can I compare MP3 files with diff ? I can find hashes of MP3 files. But can I use diff for checking their integrity ?
2. How diff handles non-text files ?
3. How to compare all files in two different directories using diff ? If some file is corrupted or tampered, will diff report it ?
4. How to find checksums of whole directories for comparison ?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Could one boil these four questions down into "How may I compare two directory hierarchies containing varying types of files in order to detect whether any file was changed?". Note that one question should primarily focus on a single issue.

Comment: @they yes. I want to ask exactly the same, but I want more elaborated answer especially for those 4 points.

Comment: You can only diff files by name. So if you have a set of files where the same content may be present under different filenames (e.g. multiple downloads), then you need to do a full diff of every file against every other file to find the duplicates. With a checksum approach, you can group all files with the same content easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point in making a numbered list when some points include multiple questions? I've tried counting the questio marks and used those to number my answers

1. Yes
2. Yes - but you'll mostly just be told that the files are different.
3. No
4. It will tell you that the files are binary and different
5. Write a command that loops over the files
6. No
7. That's not particularly well-defined, you might be interested in
   [Get checksum of directory on bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228741/get-checksum-of-directory-on-bash) and/or [Diffing two directories recursively based on checksums?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330933/diffing-two-directories-recursively-based-on-checksums)

To compare binary files you might get slightly better results with `cmp`, but that also doesn't care about the actual type. If what you really want is to find exact duplicates, look at `fdupes`/`jdupes`. If you also need to find similar, non-exact duplicates, you'll need something that can fingerprint the files and compare the fingerprints. I don't know of any such tool for mp3 (or more generally audio - I can imagine having a collection of audio files in different formats, where some might be the same songs) files.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik for your answer..! I experimented a bit with diff after reading your answer and found that it is really helpful to find difference in any kind of files, let they are binary or text. I intentionally tampered some files, and diff was able to detect them as well. Thus, can we say that it can be interchangeable with any checksum utility to check file integrity. But checksum is helpful when we don't have actual file for comparison, but a remote copy. (Like an ISO file stored on a server is downloaded.)